# Refractive index in metamaterials

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, refraction, optical-materials

Why do metamaterials have $n<0$?
They are defined to be those materials with $\varepsilon <0$ and $\mu<0$, but the definition of the refractive index is
$$n=\sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon\mu}{\varepsilon_0\mu_0}}$$
So it should be still positive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Negative refractive index is negative](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79692/)